# Replacing the first and the last letter of a string

Tags: r, regex

I found this function that switches the first and the last letters in words.

```r
library(stringr)

words |>
    str_replace("([a-zA-Z])(.*)([a-zA-Z])","\\3\\2\\1") |>
    head(25)
```

```
[1] "a"         "ebla"      "tboua"     "ebsoluta"  "tccepa"    "tccouna"  
[7] "echieva"   "scrosa"    "tca"       "ectiva"    "lctuaa"    "dda"      
[13] "sddresa"   "tdmia"     "edvertisa" "tffeca"    "dffora"    "rftea"    
[19] "nfternooa" "ngaia"     "tgainsa"   "ega"       "tgena"     "oga"      
[25] "egrea"
```

Can somebody explain how it works?

What do these mean:
`"([a-zA-Z])(.*)([a-zA-Z])"` and `"\\3\\2\\1")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are **regular expressions** (**regex**) and are used for complex operations on character strings.

`str_replace()` identifies, from a given string, patterns listed in the first string, and replaces them with the pattern in the second string.

`([a-zA-Z])(.*)([a-zA-Z])` means:

1. Identify three groups (delimited by brackets: `()()()`）
2. The first and third group contain a single letter from a to z (or A to Z): `[a-zA-Z]`
3. The third group contains any number (`*`) of any characters (`.`)

Together, this means: identify the first and last letter of each string.

For more info I recommend [the R4DS chapter on strings](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html?q=regex#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions).

You can also paste a regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to get an explanation - but it's a bit technical if you don't know the basics.

Comment: @benson23 what about "\\3\\2\\1"), and is there another simple function that does the same?

Comment: @David To my knowledge, no. But another regex that's a bit shorter which pretty much do the same thing would be `^(\\w)(.*)(\\w)$`, where `^` signals the start of a string and `$` signals the end. `\\w` matches any single letter, number or underscore. It is indeed less specific than `[a-zA-Z]` but is shorter to type (and also make sure we are capturing the first and last letter)

Comment: @David the `\\3\\2\\1` is what we call a backreference in regex which is to "call" the value within each capture group (`\\1` refer to the first values surrounded by bracket `()`, `\\2` refer to the second and `\\3` the third), I don't think you can replace them with a function.